# Loading images into docker-in-docker (dind) running in k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

So I have docker-in-docker running as a sidecar in a pod with /var/lib/docker pointed to emptyDir: {}.

I need to load a couple of images into it after it comes up to have it work as I need it to. I can docker save them from my repo and move them to storage on the node without too much angst.

Is there a simple, accepted way pull them in or do I need to experiment with another container with docker-cmds and scripting something?

Comment: do you mean `docker pull` them in, or load the tar that was produced by `docker save`? But either way, I wouldn't expect there to be any magic -- are you encountering an error or is this just a general "poll" type question?

Comment: Well I must have had something misconfigured initially because the application that was using the DinD finally managed to docker pull them and things moved forward.
My question though still stands. It takes a while to drag these images down. If there were a way to prime the thing when it initializes that would be much better. I just haven't yet found a simple way to do it that doesn't require additional containers and was wondering what others had done in this situation.